# WordPress auto login after registration not working

Tags: users, hooks, login, user-registration, authentication

I looked up a bunch of threads trying to figure out how to automatically log a user in after registration, and came up with this.

```
function automatically_log_me_in( $user_id ) {
    $user = get_user_by('id',$user_id);
    $username = $user->user_nicename;
    $user_id = $user->ID;
    wp_set_current_user($user_id, $username);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
    do_action('wp_login', $username, $user);
    exit;
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'automatically_log_me_in' );
```

According to many responses I've seen, `wp_set_auth_cookie` and `wp_set_current_user` alone should be enough to log a user in by ID, but even this isn't doing anything.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: how are you registering users? via `wp-login.php`? this does successfully log someone in when I test it, though you short-circuit the rest of the script when you `exit`.

Comment: also note that when you set a cookie, it can't be read until the next request, so you need to redirect somewhere for WordPress to recognize that you're logged in.

Comment: I'm registering users with a custom registration form that directs to `wp-login.php`. Could that be it?

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer** - Your original function (mostly) works.  This is your function edited to do what it needs to do:

```
function automatically_log_me_in( $user_id ) {
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
    wp_redirect( home_url( '/some-ending-page/' ) );
    exit(); 
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'automatically_log_me_in' );
```

**Long answer** - here is an explanation of why this is the answer.

The suggestion of `wp_signon()` won't do it.  You need the user credentials for that, and barring passing credentials, that function will attempt to retrieve the posted username ('log') and password ('pwd') from the form and I would assume 'pwd' would be lacking from that.

The other answers make suggestions that unfortunately don't apply in this specific instance. Several are suggestions that are plugin specific.  As the developer of one of those (WP-Members), as much as I'd like you to use that plugin, suggesting to use `wpmem_post_register_data` doesn't do you any good if you're not using WP-Members.

Using `wp_set_current_user()` as your original thought is the correct way to do it; but **you need to redirect the user at the end** so they are seen as logged in.

The `user_register` action passes the ID of the just registered user, so I'm not sure why you would change the value of `$user_id` by setting it to `$user->ID` when you already have the value.  And the only reason to get the user object in your original function is to get the username. This is an optional argument for `wp_set_current_user()` and the `wp_login` action so I wouldn't even bother with that.  (I'd ditch the `wp_login` action because all that is doing is putting a hook into your process for outside functions to hook to.  Whether you want/need this requires more information than your OP provides.)  All that is just wasted bits in your code, IMO.

Does your registration process end at this point? The auth cookie is set and the user is logged in.  However, that won't be read until the next page request so you need to redirect the user to whatever page you want them to end on using `wp_redirect()` after which you need to `exit()`.

Comment: Work for me ... thanx

Answer (score 1):

> I'm registering users with a custom registration form that directs to
>   wp-login.php

Then you could use [`wp_signon`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) function. Provide more details for suggesting another solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm registering users with a custom registration form that directs to `wp-login.php`. Could that be it?

Try one of these functions. You can chose which page to redirect to in the first one. The second one is more like the one you were trying. They may work or help.

```
add_action( 'tml_new_user_registered', 'tml_new_user_registered' );
function tml_new_user_registered( $user_id ) {
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, false, is_ssl() );
    wp_redirect( admin_url( 'profile.php' ) );
    exit;
}
```

or

```
add_action( 'wpmem_post_register_data', 'my_registration_hook', 1 );
function my_registration_hook( $fields ) {
    $user_login = $fields['username'];
    $user_id = $fields['ID'];

    wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_login );
    do_action( 'wp_login', $user_login );

    wp_set_current_user( $fields['ID'] );
}
```

Comment: Neither of these suggestions solve the OP's problem. These are plugin specific - one is for Theme My Login and the other for WP-Members. As one of those plugin's authors, I'd love for you to use my plugin - but that's not the solution to this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this code before any headers are sent to the client.  Try segregating the login code.

This question is almost a year old, so please let us know what, if anything worked.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me. I am using WP-Members plugin (and hook).

```
add_action( 'wpmem_post_register_data', 'my_registration_hook', 1 );
function my_registration_hook( $fields ) {
    wp_set_current_user( $fields['ID'] );
    $creds = array(
        'user_login'    => $fields['username'],
        'user_password' => $fields['password'],
        'rememember'    => false
    );
    wp_signon( $creds, false );
}
```

Comment: I think this is not a very good answer for the problem described in the question.

Comment: Why not? WP-Members plugin?

Comment: Because the action `wpmem_post_register_data` doesn't exists on WordPress, so it can not be the answer to the question.