# How to auto login after registration?

Tags: redirect, user-registration, wp-redirect, wp-login-form

I create an user using

```
 $user_id = wp_create_user($username, $password, $email);
```

After creating the user I want them to auto login and so according to [ravi patel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19997904/5620862), I have added the following code in my functions.php.

```
function auto_login_new_user( $user_id ) {
    wp_set_current_user($user_id);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );//`[Codex Ref.][1]
    wp_redirect( home_url() ); // You can change home_url() to the specific URL,such as "wp_redirect( 'http://www.wpcoke.com' )";
    exit;
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_login_new_user' );
```

But as expected, the following warning popped up.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /opt/lampp/htdocs/vuewordpress/wp-includes/link-template.php:3840) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/vuewordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 928
```

How do I get rid off this and redirect the user on the same page from they try to sign up?

I understand one thing the I need to run the code before the header is written. May be I need to somehow hook this action in `init`. But I dont know how to do it.

Any help is highly appreciable!!

Comment: You'd need to share the code responsible for creating users

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
function auto_login_new_user( $user_id ) {
    wp_set_current_user($user_id);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
    wp_redirect( home_url() ); // You can change home_url() to the specific URL,such as "wp_redirect( 'http://www.wpcoke.com' )";
    exit();
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_login_new_user' );
```

Taken from this SO answer: [WordPress auto login after registration not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156680/wordpress-auto-login-after-registration-not-working)

Comment: Will this work on register form on woocommerce my account page?